# Draw map dynamically by .shp file

Tags: c#, gis, arcgis, qgis, esri-javascript-api

I am working on a c# project where i have to draw a map on the basis of shape(**.shp**) file. Is there any kind of library in c# by which i can dynamically create maps with the provided shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [ESRI ArcObject](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#default.htm) library, but it requires an ArcGIS license.

You could also give a try to those open source libraries: [SharpMap](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sharpmap), [EasyGIS.NET](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/) or [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial)

DotSpatial and EsayGIS.NET seems to be the best choices.

Comment: Library recommendation tools are off-topic, please vote to close them instead of answering them.